# Sudoku Solver Not Solving All Sudoku Puzzles

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku

I have been working on a sudoku solver for some time now, and I just implemented the detection for if there is only one space a number can go, and it does not work. Also, some previous code seems to not have worked at all.

```py
def square_solver(board):
    """Remove confirmed values from the possible values in the squares"""
    global possibleBoard
    # Sets up a modulator to multiply by to get the 3x3 grid of one square with the first value being the rows and the second being the column
    blockNum = [0, 0]
    for _ in range(9):
        # A loop that checks the 9 numbers in one of the squares
        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                if not board[(blockNum[0] * 3) + x][(blockNum[0] * 3) + y] == " ":  # Checks if that square a number
                    # Checks all the empty spots in one of the squares for that number, then removes them
                    for z in range(3):
                        for w in range(3):
                            try:
                                # Removes the number from the possible board
                                possibleBoard[(blockNum[0] * 3) + z][(blockNum[1] * 3) + w].remove(
                                    board[(blockNum[0] * 3) + x][(blockNum[1] * 3) + y])
                            # If it can't do anything, run this
                            except (ValueError, AttributeError):
                                pass
        blockNum = block_num(blockNum)
    return board
```

```py
counter = [0] * 9
    blockNum = [0, 0]
    for _ in range(9):
        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                # Checks the possible board and counts how many time a possible number appears
                if type(possibleBoard[(blockNum[0] * 3) + x][(blockNum[0] * 3) + y]) == list:
                    for z in range(len(possibleBoard[(blockNum[0] * 3) + x][(blockNum[0] * 3) + y])):
                        counter[possibleBoard[(blockNum[0] * 3) + x][(blockNum[0] * 3) + y][z] - 1] += 1
        for x in range(len(counter)):
            # Checks to see if there was any times only one number appeared
            if counter[x] == 1:
                for y in range(3):
                    for z in range(3):
                        try:
                            # Finds the solo number, and makes that number definite
                            if (x + 1) in possibleBoard[(blockNum[0] * 3) + y][(blockNum[0] * 3) + z]:
                                board[(blockNum[0] * 3) + y][(blockNum[0] * 3) + z] = x + 1
                        except TypeError:
                            pass
        blockNum = block_num(blockNum)
        # Rests the counter
        counter = [0] * 9
```

I have rewritten both section of code, and both times it has not solved the sudoku puzzles. I can't figure out what is wrong but I think it might have something to do with the `board[(blockNum[0] * 3) + x][(blockNum[0] * 3) + y]` sections.

The full code is [here](https://github.com/K00lmans/Sudoku-Solver).

Comment: Maybe sudokus are not as simple to solve as your algorithm assumes.

Comment: @khelwood I have been using this sudoku puzzle (https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d84f759d69cbb820e584cf8b35a8505254e5c584/0_0_431_431/master/431.jpg?width=300&quality=85&auto=format&fit=max&s=2e1f0111652f3e637c62abab33a7d1ff) and an online solver (https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm) and were my code gets stuck is a place that according to the sudoku solver is solvable by my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have the code segment `board[(blockNum[0] * 3) + x][(blockNum[0] * 3) + y]` all of your problems stem from the fact it should be `board[(blockNum[0] * 3) + x][(blockNum[1] * 3) + y]`. Since it was counting the rows and columns with the same number, it would only go diagonally. Changing these around fix's the problem.

Comment: I spent at least 10 hours staring at the code and I missed it until now.